# PL/SQL - The function deosn't return multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I wanted to select 10 highly paid employees from the "employees" table, but the function returnes only 1 row. How to get multiple rows in this case? My  subquery for selecting employees works well, but when I call function it returns 1 row.

This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sal
RETURN Varchar2

IS cursor c_emp is (select first_name, last_name from (select first_name, last_name, row_number() 
over(order by salary desc) as ranking from employees) where ranking <= 10);

v_first employees.first_name%type;
v_last employees.last_name%type;

begin
open c_emp;
fetch c_emp into v_first, v_last;
close c_emp;
return v_first || ' ' || v_last;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
  THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('Error');
     when others then dbms_output.put_line('Other Error');
END;
  
select f_sal from dual;
```

Comment: You only fetch once. But you only return a single string value, too. Why are you using a function at all - because you've been told to, as an exercise? You need to think about what form the result should take - a ref cursor, a collection, ...?

Comment: @Alex Poole Yes, I was told to use a function. I suspect the function returns 1 value because the function fetched 1 row or Varchar2 cannot return multiple values. Should I use something else instead of CURSOR?

Comment: While the fundamental problem you are asking about is due to the fact that you only fetch 1 row from the cursor, then exit,  I agree that this is not usually a proper use of a function.  I'd like to see how the function is actually being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: Use a collection

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f_sal
RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
IS 
  v_names SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
  SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_names
  FROM   employees
  ORDER BY salary DESC
  FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;

  return v_names;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE(f_sal);
```

---

#### Option 2: Use a pipelined function and iterate over a cursor into a collection

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sal
RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
  FOR n IN (
    SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name AS name
    FROM   employees
    ORDER BY salary DESC
    FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
  )
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (n.name);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE(f_sal);
```

---

#### Option 3: Return a cursor

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f_sal
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS 
  v_names SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_names FOR
    SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name AS name
    FROM   employees
    ORDER BY salary DESC
    FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;

  return v_names;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_names SYS_REFCURSOR := f_sal();
  v_name VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  LOOP
    FETCH v_names INTO v_name;
    EXIT WHEN v_names%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_name );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ad79e313d62744319d6b8abbee98d798)*